# Why Java localDateTime does not recognize Canada/Yukon as GMT-7?

Tags: java, time, timezone

Canada/Yukon timezone no longer observe DST (source https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada/yukon) and is now permanently GMT-7. But when I tried this:

```
ZonedDateTime nowZoned = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-02-03T08:04:00").atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Yukon"));
```

nowZoned is shown as 2021-02-03T00:04-08:00[Canada/Yukon].

Does it mean that java.time library does not update when some timezones have decided not to observe DST or decided to move ahead of the clock permanently? What are some ways to work around this issues? I thought about manually checking for these but there are simply way too many timezones to handle them manually. Thanks!

Comment: *"Does it mean that java.time library does not update when some timezones have decided not to observe DST or decided to move ahead of the clock permanently?"* - At a guess, yes.  This information (AFAIK) is stored internally to the JVM and so would require an update to the JVM

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes indeed, the [Yukon time zone rules changed](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/yukon-canada-permanent-dst.html) in early 2020. The politicians there decided to stay on [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) indefinitely, using an offset of -07:00 year-round. So the sun will never again be overhead at noon.

Staying on DST year-round is the new fad among politicians around the world. Countries such as [Morocco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Morocco) and [Turkey](https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/turkey-continues-with-daylight-saving-time-permanently-137461) have gone that way. Others are headed that way, [such as Washington State](https://mynorthwest.com/2688382/washington-push-daylight-saving-time-permanently-2021/) in the United States.

Your code:

> `ZonedDateTime nowZoned = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-02-03T08:04:00").atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Yukon"));`

… is overwrought. Simply put a `Z` at the end of your input string if that date and time is intended to be a moment as seen in UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    Inatant
    .parse("2021-02-03T08:04:00Z")
    .atZone(
        ZoneId.of( "Canada/Yukon" )
    )
;
```

You asked:

> Does it mean that java.time library does not update when some timezones have decided not to observe DST or decided to move ahead of the clock permanently?

Politicians around the world have shown a predilection towards changing the rules of the time zones in their jurisdiction. They do so with surprising frequency. And some do so with astonishingly little forewarning.

The rules are stored in a [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) file. When politicians change the rules, [ICANN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN)/[IANA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) publishes a new updated version of the tzdata. This typically happens a few times a year.

And, no, there is no automatic immediate updating on your computer. As a SysAdmin or DBA, you are responsible for these updates. Of course, you need not update unless a time zone of interest to your company changes.

You will find at least two or three of these on your machines.

- Your **JVM** has one embedded. Updates to the JVM will typically include the latest tzdata. But that Java update may not come soon enough. So you may need to manually obtain a tzdata file, ad replace the one in your JVM. [Oracle provides a tool](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html) to assist. But I’m not aware of its current licensing terms, so study their terms. Or check with the vendor of your JVM such as Azul Systems, Adoptium, SAP, Amazon, Microsoft, BellSoft, Red Hat/IBM, etc.
- Your host **operating system** such as macOS, BSD, Linux, Windows, etc. has a copy of the tzdata. While updating this tzdata does not affect your Java apps, you’ll want to update it for other apps.
- Sophisticated **database servers** such as Postgres also keep their own internal copy of tzdata. Update as needed by either manual replacement or through an updated version of the DBMS.

Every SysAdmin & DBA should consider subscribing to the [tzdata announcement mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/mailman/listinfo/tz-announce).